# Is there any advantage doing a guard let on a table view cell or not?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have seen people writing this code inside a table view delegate

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                      cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! SuitCell? else {
      fatalError()
    }
  ...
}
```

now consider this other code

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                          cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! SuitCell

    ...
}
```

Won't both codes crash at the same lines if the cell is not dequeued?

Is there any difference? I am not seeing it.

Comment: How can one be not sure of the class of the cell if the class is in the project?

Comment: so the guard is unnecessary and the dequeueReusableCell will not be nil. Right? I mean, if everything is local.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself correctly. I am talking about the cast. If there is only one type of cell associated to one class, the cast will never fail.

Comment: my point is this. If the cast and the dequeue never fails, there is no point of using the `guard` or `if let` if this is the case. A plain `let` will work.

Comment: yes, I know. Mine forbids. I was just trying to understand that. Please convert your comments to an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: @matt,  `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` can return `nil`. The `forIndexPath:` variant can't. The first block of code will crash if you dequeue a reusable cell and it isn't the right class (an impossibility really). The second block will crash in that case and when you have not previously put any cells in the reuse pool

Comment: It was the cast to an optional that clued me in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` can return `nil` in the case where there are no cells in the re-use pool (i.e. When the tableview is first shown).  When it returns `nil` it is your responsibility to instantiate a cell of the appropriate type.

Therefore, this block of code:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! SuitCell? else {
  fatalError()
}
```

says "If you get a cell from the re-use pool and it isn't an instance of `SuitCell`, crash, but `nil` is OK" (Note the cast to an optional)

While this block of code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! SuitCell
```

Says "Crash if you don't get an instance of `SuitCell`, or youn get `nil`", so this will crash when the tableview is first shown.

`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` isn't really used any more.  You would use the newer (but still been around since iOS 6) `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:,for:)` variant as it *always* returns a cell and you can expect it to be the right class (or you will quickly find your problem during development):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SuitCell
```